# .pop() equivalent in scala

Tags: scala

I have worked on python 
In python there is a function .pop() which delete the last value in a list and return that 
deleted value
ex. x=[1,2,3,4]
x.pop() will return 4

I was wondering is there is a scala equivalent for this function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just wish to retrieve the last value, you can call `x.last`. This won't remove the last element from the list, however, which is immutable. Instead, you can call `x.init` to obtain a list consisting of all elements in `x` except the last one - again, without actually changing `x`. So:

```
val lastEl = x.last
val rest = x.init
```

will give you the last element (`lastEl`), the list of all bar the last element (`rest`), and you still also have the original list (`x`).

Comment: Just to know, how is it better than calling last and get a new list after calling dropRight(1)?

Comment: `dropRight(1)` will do the job as well (as will `x.reverse.tail`, and various other possible calls). Fewer characters to type, though! :)

Comment: unlike pop x.reverse.tail will be O(n)

Comment: @om-nom-nom True, there are performance differences between the various options - if performance is an issue here, though, using an alternate data structure such as `Vector` or `Queue` (as per @0__'s answer), or restructuring your code so that the element you want is most naturally to be found at the front of the list, not the back, might be better choices.

Comment: if using list, consider changing the order of your algo : `val firstE = x.head; val rest = x.tail` should be constant time with list

Comment: `someList.pop()` in python is O(1) where as in scala `someCollection.dropRight(1)` is O(n) even for ArrayBuffer.

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of [different collection types](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) in Scala, each with its own set of supported and/or well performing operations.

In Scala, a `List` is an immutable cons-cell sequence like in Lisp. Getting the `last` element is not a well optimised solution (the `head` element is fast). Similarly `Queue` and `Stack` are optimised for retrieving an element and the rest of the structure from one end particularly. You could use either of them if your order is reversed.

Otherwise, `Vector` is a good performing general structure which is fast both for `head` and `last` calls:

```
val v = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
val init :+ last = v  // uses pattern matching extractor `:+` to get both init and last
```

Where `last` would be the equivalent of your `pop` operation, and `init` is the sequence with the last element removed (you can also use `dropRight(1)` as suggested in the other answers). To just retrieve the last element, use `v.last`.

Answer (score 7):

I tend to use

```
val popped :: newList = list
```

which assigns the first element of the list to `popped` and the remaining list to `newList`

Comment: Note: this pops from the head of the list (which is the first, not last, element)

Answer (score 4):

The first answer is correct but you can achieve the same doing:

```
val last = x.last
val rest = x.dropRight(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to relax your need for immutable structures, there's always Stack and Queue:

```
val poppable = scala.collection.mutable.Stack[String]("hi", "ho")
val popped = poppable.pop
```

Similar to Python's ability to pop multiple elements, Queue handles that:

```
val multiPoppable = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[String]("hi", "ho")
val allPopped = poppable.dequeueAll(_ => true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is `mutable.Queue`, use `dequeue` function

```
  /** Returns the first element in the queue, and removes this element
   *  from the queue.
   *
   *  @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException
   *  @return the first element of the queue.
   */
  def dequeue(): A =
    if (isEmpty)
      throw new NoSuchElementException("queue empty")
    else {
      val res = first0.elem
      first0 = first0.next
      decrementLength()
      res
    }
```